# Paypal ipn - Empty IPN and wrong date. Used to work

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a website with a simple ticket shop built into it using IPN. It has been working for the past month and I left it alone. I was working on another payment site on the same webhost and for the first time i specified the "notification_url". I noticed that I couldn't get any response from PayPal on my new build and left it there. I then checked to see that my orginal system was still working at least; It was not.

For some reason when i check my IPN history the "latest delivery atempt" is "1984/12/14 04:53:12 CET (UTC+1)". The worst thing is that it also sais "Notification url: ". Empty.

This aparently returned 200 and success allthough my access logs show no traffic to my ipn-page. I have logs running and i havn't modified either code. I can access the IPN url manualt and it will get logged. No html login and no restrictions.

Heres my payment form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="8TPEJKFGZEJBS">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="sv_SE">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$text.'">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'.$order_id.'">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$cost.'">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="SEK">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mywebsite.com/?page=13&done">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://mywebsite.com/?  page=13&cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" style="border: none;" src="images/buy.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - Det tryggare, enklare sättet att betala online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/sv_SE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

What is wrong and what should i try to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a field "notify_url" in your form. This URL is your IPN file url.

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mywebsite.com/?page=13&done">
```

For more details:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: I have never had to do that before and i have enabled the settings linking to the correct ipn in my profile.

Never the less i added "<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mywebsite.com/api/paypal.php">" and proccessed a payment. It did not work.

The result in ipn history was:

    Date: 1984/11/03 18:24:24 CET (UTC+1)
    message url:

Comment: @user2256486: Please try to debug (by mail/write file) post data in IPN file on the top on the this file.

Comment: I am writing sql-logs on every request in the IPN file. It is not getting any requests. The first thing it does is to log that the file is loaded and request data, if there is.

Comment: I found the issue:
My server was being moved and they changed my nameservers. Paypal sent requests to the new ip adress while my provider hadn't updated it. I visited the old site.